# Windows LoadMenu error: "The specified resource name cannot be found in the image file."

Tags: c++, windows, resources, contextmenu

I'm writing a program that, among other things, needs to display a context menu on right-click. I'm trapping `WM_NOTIFY`, the identifier of the control being clicked on, and `NM_RCLICK`. That all works great.

The problem comes in when I'm processing that right-click:

```
case NM_RCLICK:
{
    HMENU Popup = LoadMenu(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_NED_MENU));
    if ( !Popup ) {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        char* buf;
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, 0, err, 0, buf, 1<<19, 0);
        _ERROR("LoadMenu(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_NED_MENU)); Error '%s' thrown; no menu loaded.", buf);
        delete [] buf;
    }
    Popup = GetSubMenu(Popup, 0);
    CheckMenuItem(Popup, 1, MF_CHECKED|MF_BYPOSITION);

    POINT Point;
    GetCursorPos(&Point);

    switch (TrackPopupMenu(Popup, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD, Point.x, Point.y, 0, GetActiveWindow(), NULL)) {
        // ...
```

Primarily, `LoadMenu(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_NED_MENU));` is returning `NULL`, and I'm getting an error message that states that "The specified resource name cannot be found in the image file."

Now, IDR_NED_MENU is the ID of a menu I have in the `.rc` file, and I've included the corresponding `.rc.h` file in this `.cpp` file. The actual dialog window IDs contained in the same `.rc` file work perfectly. This code is further copied and pasted from another project where the `LoadMenu` call worked perfectly: I did recreate the `IDR_NED_MENU` from scratch, though, and the IDs are somewhat different (but they do match between the `.rc` file and the `.cpp` file that has the code snippet I've pasted here); originally I'd accidentally created the menu in a separate `.rc` file so I sought to rectify that here. I noticed that in Visual Studio's Resource View, the dialogs are contained in the Dialog folder, while this is contained in the Menu folder (sensible), but I'm not sure what, if any, difference that makes.

Why would I be getting this error? Why can't it find `IDR_NED_MENU`?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and this is not an MFC project. I'm not sure what, if any, other relevant details I should include; let me know in comments and I'll edit-update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `LoadMenu` must be a handle to your executable image where the resource resides. The handle is the first `HINSTANCE` that you get in `WinMain`. Alternatively you can obtain it by a call to `GetModuleHandle(0)`.

Comment: Hrm. In the project I'd copied this code from, it definitely used `LoadMenu(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));` (`IDR_MENU1` was the old ID), and that worked. I tried `LoadMenu(GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_NED_MENU));` anyway, though, and now I'm still getting a `NULL` return value, and `GetLastError` is now giving an error message that just says `(null)`...

Comment: Aha, but that did lead me to the answer: since I'm modifying a project I did not write entirely myself, there was a call to `CreateDialogParam` that I hadn't written, and did work: it used a global `HINSTANCE` variable named `hModule` for the first parameter, and using that for my `LoadMenu` call has worked! And just as ybungalobill suggested, `hModule` was initially defined in `DllMain` to be equal to `hDllHandle`. Thanks!

Comment: @DragoonWraith: ah, if it's a DLL project it's another story, and you had to say that in the OP. Every DLL loaded by your app may have it's own resource with the same ID, so you must specify the HINSTANCE of the DLL you want to use.